# Can't we submit tvOS app to store?

Tags: tvos

I did archive my tvos app and validate with Xcode7.1Beta, then show below error message.It not yet start to recieve tvos app on appstore?

> An error occured. Archive did not contain known itunes platform.

Comment: Can you enlist some of the things you already tried so far?

Answer (score 8):

You need to upgrade xcode to 7.1 beta 2, you can then actually upload your tvOS app for testflight testing and to check that it uploads ok.

To submit for the store, you will need the GM as the previous answers says.

Answer (score 5):

Apple will send enrolled developers email when the App store opens for submissions for a new major OS version.  This usually happens only after the GM version of the beta Xcode with the beta OS SDK is released.  tvOS is currently in beta.

Answer (score 0):

You can as of last night at 11pm.  Give it a try now.

Answer (score 0):

Make it sure that you upgrade your OSX El Capitan at the app store, if you are running a beta version. iTunes Connect won't let you submit the app built with beta version of OSX or Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

recently encountered the same problem, both your macos and xcode must be public releases (not beta) to submit your app, my solution was to create a small partition on my macbook , install a clean osx and xcode and use this partition whenever I need to publish an app. This way I can still use beta's for mac and xcode.